# Как присвоить имена столбцам в массиве?

Tags: python, numpy, csv, обработка-данных

Помогите, не могу понять, только изучаю Python

Необходимо создать таблицу с именами столбцов из вот такой таблицы (она создается внутри программы, как временная при помощи слияния трех массивов код для этого слияния привожу ниже. Сделал копию части таблицы в формате CSV, ссылка https://disk.yandex.ru/d/uhjAYDykU7P7rQ
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что нужно получить на выходе? Надо получить точно такую же таблицу, с теми же самыми данными, но с именами столбцов.
Данные в массиве под обозначениями (столбы) 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 должны быть в таблице в столбцах с соответствующим наименованием,
columns = ['data0', 'data1', 'data2', 'data3', 'data4', 'data5'].
Подскажите, как это сделать? Или присвоить имена столбцам в уже созданной таблице? Обращаю внимание, что эти данные не загружаются извне, а получаются в результате работы внутри программы.

```
rez1 = np.c_[X_test, y_test, prediction_columns]
```

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе небольшой, но воспроизводимый пример входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: Спасибо за замечание и совет, еще не освоился на данном ресурсе) Исправил текст вопроса. Прошу помощи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Numpy (а тем более в базовом Python) имена столбцам массива задать невозможно в принципе.
Имена столбцов можно задать в таблице (двумерной), которая создается в Pandas.
В Pandas DataFrame создается методом  DataFrame, у которого есть параметр columns, который как раз и принимает список имен столбцов создаваемого объекта.

```
pd.DataFrame(data=.... #сам массив
         index=.... #откруда брать индекс, если нужен
         columns=.... #список имен столбцов
```

Второй вариант - создание через словарь столбцов, например так:

```
dataset = pd.DataFrame({'Столбец 1': data[:, 0], 'Столбец 2': data[:, 1]})
```

Ну и несколько видоизмененный способ:

```
dataset = pd.DataFrame()
dataset['Столбец 1']=data[:, 0]
dataset['Столбец 2']=data[:, 1]
```

Comment: Спасибо добрый человек!!! Это сработало!

Comment: @Xray321 - если сработало - то https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

Пример с использованием модуля Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("rez1.csv", header=None, sep=";").add_prefix("data")
```

чтобы создать pandas DataFrame из numpy матрицы `arr`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(arr).add_prefix("data")
```

результат:

```
In [119]: df
Out[119]:
   data0  data1  data2  data3  data4  data5
0     31     33     26     37     29     31
1     19     10     14      6     18      9
2     26     33     32     20     24     31
3     10     18     26     16     22     19
4     13     25     14     18     21     16
5     23     34     31     27     23     42
6     17     24     22     20     11     20
7     15     24     20     14     20     10
8     15     20     10     26     17     13
9     22     39     28     33     27     20

In [120]: df.columns.to_list()
Out[120]: ['data0', 'data1', 'data2', 'data3', 'data4', 'data5']
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!